# HTML being pushed to a second line on nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a navbar header with a logo on the left, search box in the center, and a small menu on the right similar to Reverb's. Here:

[image]

I've gotten it pretty close but for some reason, my menu is being pushed down to a second line because my search bar is too long.

[image]

I've tried putting in the row and breaking the sections up into smaller col-sm-4 divs, but that messes things up more (FYI, I'm using Bootstrap 4).

Here is my html. Haven't done really any CSS other than change the default colors.

```
<header class="header">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm fixed top mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                            NAVBAR
                </a>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            By
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">User name</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Member type</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Company</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Genre</a>
                            <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button" placeholder="Search for...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Go!</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </nav>    
    </header>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to keep the icons to the right of the search from wrapping, then you could try something like this:

```
ul.justify-content-end {
  min-width:200px;
}
```

Comment: It worked in a fiddle. What's the maximum width of your website container?

Comment: Not sure. I don't have a maximum width set on it so it would be whatever the default is for a <div class="container"> in bootstrap

Comment: Please see this fiddle:( https://jsfiddle.net/cg6035t0/ ). If this isn't the behavior that you're seeing, then there may be something else happening in your code.

Comment: In your posted screen capture, it appears that you added another item, which is why the solution didn't hold. Try this instead: ( https://jsfiddle.net/cg6035t0/2/ ). This solution isn't dependent on fixed widths.